# Sony Vaio EB1E0E IDE Mode

Tags: sony-vaio, spinrite

I am trying to use [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) on my Sony Vaio EB1E0E, and for this I need to enable the IDE mode. However when I go to the advanced tab in the bios I only see the Vt-x enabling and disabling.

Any suggestions on how I can go about enabling IDE mode in the BIOS?